# How to convert all the date format to a timestamp for date column?

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using PySpark version 3.0.1. I am reading a csv file as a PySpark dataframe having 2 date column. But when I try to print the schema both column is populated as string type.

[image]

[image]

Above screenshot attached is a Dataframe and schema of the Dataframe.

How to convert the row values there in both the date column to timestamp format using pyspark?

I have tried many things but all code is required the current format but how to convert to proper timestamp if I am not aware of what format is coming in csv file.

I have tried below code as wellb but this is creating a new column with null value

```
df1 = df.withColumn('datetime', col('joining_date').cast('timestamp'))
print(df1.show())
print(df1.printSchema())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since there are two different date types, you need to convert using two different date formats, and coalesce the results.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df.withColumn(
    'datetime',
    F.coalesce(
        F.to_timestamp('joining_date', 'MM-dd-yy'),
        F.to_timestamp('joining_date', 'MM/dd/yy')
    )
)

result.show()
+------------+-------------------+
|joining_date|           datetime|
+------------+-------------------+
|    01-20-20|2020-01-20 00:00:00|
|    01/19/20|2020-01-19 00:00:00|
+------------+-------------------+
```

If you want to convert all to a single format:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df.withColumn(
    'datetime',
    F.date_format(
        F.coalesce(
            F.to_timestamp('joining_date', 'MM-dd-yy'),
            F.to_timestamp('joining_date', 'MM/dd/yy')
        ),
        'MM-dd-yy'
    )
)

result.show()
+------------+--------+
|joining_date|datetime|
+------------+--------+
|    01-20-20|01-20-20|
|    01/19/20|01-19-20|
+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But actually the issue is I am not aware of different format which is there raw csv file.

Comment: @Nayanjain You can try these two formats first, and see how much can be converted

Comment: Actually I have tried this already. It is giving me correct result. But it is a batch data and the requirement is to handle the dynamic date format and convert it to one format

Comment: @Nayanjain you need to provide all date formats - I'm afraid Spark cannot guess the date formats of your data.

Comment: @Nayanjain I've added another example to convert all dates to a single format. See if that helps?

Comment: Okay...Is there any way by which we can identify all date/time column from raw csv file using PySpark. Because in PySpark when we print the schema of the dataframe all the date/time column is coming as string datatype.

Comment: @Nayanjain as I said, Spark cannot guess your date formats - imagine if one row has '01/01/20' - is it 1 Jan 2020, or 2001 Jan 20? Even a human cannot tell, how can Spark tell?